# Unset img src if no url is provided vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm learning vue.js 
I'm testing how it works with ajax and the wp rest api, I'm creating a custom panel theme and I want to show the content on the right side of the screen in a scrollable panel and the pages on the left side of . the screen without the possibility to scroll.
I'm able to display the content of the posts and pages, I'm getting also the featured image, and I placed it inside an `<img>` tag. I need to understand how to tell vue.js that if there isn't any url data to show the featured image, the src of the image element needs to be unset. Is this possible ?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="container-fluid content-wrapper" style="overflow:hidden;height:100vh;">
  <div class="row" id="app" style="margin:2em 0 2em 0;">
<!-- Sidebar Top Area -->
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4" id="navPanel" style="padding:2em;">
<?php $links = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'page', 'posts_per_page' => -1) ); ?>
<?php if( $links->have_posts() ): while( $links->have_posts() ): $links->the_post(); ?>
      <h1 class="home-claim" style="font-size:2em;">
        <a class="" href="#" v-on:click.prevent="getContent(<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>)" ><?php the_title(); ?></a>
      </h1>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
<!-- Post/Pages Content -->
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8" id="contentPanel" style="padding:0 0 2em 0;overflow:auto;height:100vh;">
<!-- Image here -->
      <img class="img-fluid w-100" v-if="featuredImage" v-bind:src="featuredImage" />
      <div class="" id="" v-html="content"></div>

    </div>
<!-- Sidebar Bottom Area -->
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script>
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){

  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      content: null,
      featuredImage: null,
    },
    mounted: function(){

    },
    methods: {
      getContent: function(id){
        console.log('method Fired!');
        var self = this;
        console.log(id);
        var url = 'wp-json/wp/v2/pages/'+id+'?_embed';
        $.getJSON( url, function(data){
          console.log(data);
          self.content = data.content.rendered;
          self.featuredImage = data._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0].source_url;
          //console.log(data._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0].source_url);
          //console.log(data.content.rendered);
        });
      }

    }
  });

  }); // doc ready
}(jQuery));
</script>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I've also noticed that only for a page I have, the wp api will return a 401 code for the featured image. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: i see that you have a v-if on the img - so why bother unsetting the src? i suspect that the src isnt actually null, but rather an empty string. i would add something like if (self.featuredImage == "") self.featuredImage = null; in the getJSON callback.

Comment: a side note: combining PHP, jQuery and Vue.js into your application makes the code automatically non-idiomatic. these days i have almost no need for jQuery when using Vue. Use Axios for JSON, etc! And you should try to remove the php code from out there as well. Move it to a service or a wrapper, etc. Debugging will be much easier.

Comment: @ZPiDER I'm using the php inside the code because I need to pass the id to get the posts/pages content using `$.getJSON`. I don't know axios so I'm using jquery. The v-if didn't work as expected, If an image is loaded and another post didn't have a featured image, the old one will remain and this isn't what I want.

Comment: `<img  :src="featuredImage" :onerror="`javascript:this.src='${defaultImage}'`" :alt="item.name" ondragstart="return false;">`. `defaultImage` is your image url.it can is base64 or url

Comment: There isn't a default image, I take them from the REST API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unset the featuredImage before doing the load:

```js
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var app = new Vue({
      methods: {
        getContent: function(id){
          var self = this;

          // unset the image before you are loading.
          // this way it will also unset when the loading fails.
          self.featuredImage = null;

          var url = 'wp-json/wp/v2/pages/'+id+'?_embed';
          $.getJSON( url, function(data){
            self.featuredImage = data._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0].source_url;
          });
        }
      }
    });
  });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will apply this simple solution. Can you also suggest me a better way to get the post id to pass to the vue function? I'm using server-side rendering for the page list on the right panel and vue for the contents on the left panel, as you can see for now I'm passing the id using php, but it's not the ideal solution

Comment: @sisaln, you can separate the client code from the server code by doing a service-approach: for every feature that you need the server for you just create a service (api method): in your case you would have a "getPosts" service which may take a page-parameter, etc. and then returns a JSON with all the posts (`<?php echo json_encode(loadPostsfromWp());`). on your client you will call the service with `this.posts = await axios.post('/getPosts', { page: 1 });` and work with the objects (`<div v-for='post in posts'>{{ post.title }}</div>`). seems like more work at first, but will pay off quickly!

Comment: I'm not using axios, but I will consider your suggestion. Consider that wordpress has it's own way to provide some informations like the post/page ID, in my case I've used the `get_the_ID()`, maybe a better solution can be to use the `wp_localize_script` function and pass the parameter to the js directly from php function file of the theme?

Comment: In your php api implementation you are free to use any features of your framework that are available to you, so also `get_the_ID()`. it may be a challenge to establish an environment for the service though when using a framework (meaning authentication and context). Personally i'd stay away from modifying the JS through serverside scripting as this makes caching impossible, is hard to read and error-prone.

Comment: Wordpress need to use external plugins to do caching. I'm using it with vue so may scenarios aren't my case. I appreciate your suggestions

Comment: when you keep your scripts static, the browser will do the caching, you wouldnt need a wp plugin. anyway, happy to help :)